# MS Access and DLookUp, ComboBox value and #Error

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to find retrieve the "Department" from the table "tblLenderAddress", where "Lender" is equal to the selected value in the ComboBox "cmbLender".

For debugging purposes, this works fine:

```vb
=DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = 'Barclays'")
```

These, however, do not:

```vb
=DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = " & [Forms]![frmDetails]![cmbLender])

=DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = " & [Forms]![frmDetails]![cmbLender].[Value])

=DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = " & [Forms]![frmDetails]![cmbLender.value])

=DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = " & [Me]![cmbLender])
```

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but google is failing me on the first two pages of each query variation I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument in your working `DLookup` example includes quotes before and after *Barclays*.

```vb
"Lender = 'Barclays'"
```

So include those quotes when you create the argument dynamically based on the combo box's current value ...

```vb
"Lender = '" & Me!cmbLender.Value & "'"
```

Comment: me!cmblender.value still equals "#Error". However, Forms!frmDetails!cmblender.value is blank, regardless of my combo content?

Comment: =DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = '" & [Forms]![frmDetails]![cmbLender].[Value] & "'")

Comment: Do you know how to use the Access Immediate window?

Comment: Visual Basic 6 / VB.Net and Excel intermediate user; but total newbie to Access.

Comment: In that case, can you share a copy of your Access database?

Comment: Eeeee... Regretfully not due to a non-disclosure agreement.

Comment: ...Fixed it. "Text" instead of "Value". Rather unexpected. Thank you anyway, HansUp, you took me in the right direction! +1

Comment: =DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = '" & [Forms]![frmDetails]![cmbLender].[Text] & "'")

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, the fix is to;

1. Set it to "Text" instead of "Value"; and
2. Put literal wrappings around it. ' and '.

> =DLookUp("[Department]","[tblLenderAddress]","Lender = '" &
>   [Forms]![frmDetails]![cmbLender].[Text] & "'")